# Unity2D collision, if statement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, if-statement, collision-detection

I have this bit of unityCode to check if a character is grounded

```
private void FixedUpdate(){
    is_on_ground = false;

    // The player is grounded if a circlecast to the groundcheck position hits anything designated as ground
    // This can be done using layers instead but Sample Assets will not overwrite your project settings.
    Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(m_GroundCheck.position, k_GroundedRadius, m_WhatIsGround);
    for (int i = 0; i < colliders.Length; i++) {
        if (colliders[i].gameObject != gameObject) {
            is_on_ground = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone explain what the if-statement `if (colliders[i].gameObject != gameObject)` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is checking to assure the current collider found in the Overlap is not the gameObject that the script is on.

It is rather odd to have as it is a ground test to a specific layer so your object that is grounded should most likely not be part of the ground.

Comment: thank you!! yes, every layer but the player is marked as ground. so" colliders[i].gameObject == gameObject" can't actually be the case, right?

Comment: Does anything else have this script on it? Does the player have multiple colliders with a rigidbody? If it is not marked as ground I do not see a good reason to have the check. It's just to assure there is no self collision possibly with childed colliders